# Python documentation in CHM

Tags: python, documentation, chm

Where can I find Python 3.11 documentation in CHM file?

In some situations, this is more useful than the HTML format.

The last one I have is for version 3.11 alpha 4.

Answer (score 0):

The Python version (3.11 alpha 4) you specified is probably the last documentation created in CHM format. Content for software documentation is increasingly provided via the Internet in HTML format.

But I have ***not found any official notice*** from the Python project for replacing the old CHM format (see below) with HTML.

You know - for Python version 3.11 (Release) only HTML files of the documentation can be found e.g. under Windows (open `index.html` and view offline).

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Doc\html
```

Microsoft Compiled HTML Help **.chm** files being the standard for Windows application help until [it was announced in 2021](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/deprecated-chm-help-files) that .chm files are deprecated for e.g. Microsoft Dynamics AX.

Download links for ***HTMLHelp Workshop*** at [Microsoft HTML Help Downloads](https://www.help-info.de/download.html) are no longer available. Probably this is intended by Microsoft. The compiler is needed to generate CHM files!

I've archived a copy of the [HTMLHelp Workshop installer](https://www.help-info.de/download.html) for download if anyone needs it.

There are many tools that can be used to create a help file in CHM format if needed.

Comment: @rudyment In my Python 10 installation, I see:  `C:\Program Files\Python310\Doc\python3100.chm`